# Display a updating list of items on Windows Form using C#

Tags: c#

I read a MAC addresses from serial monitor and then i need to put them in the list. My problem is that only the first incoming address (string) is stored in the list. I also need the same addresses (string) not to be stored in the list more than once. I use listbox to view the items in the list. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

 namespace SerialMonitor2
 {

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort myport;
    private DateTime datetime;
    private string in_data;
    List<string> MacList = new List<string>();
    public int cnt = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myport.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message,"Error");
        }
    }

    private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 115200;
        myport.PortName = port_name_tb.Text;
        myport.Parity = Parity.None;
        myport.DataBits = 8;
        myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myport.DataReceived += myport_dataReceived;
        try
        {
            myport.Open();
            data_tb.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void myport_dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {  
        in_data = myport.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
    }

    private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        string time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;          


        if (in_data[0] == '&')
        {
            
            string[] arr = in_data.Split('#');
            string MAC = arr[0];
            string temperature = arr[3];
            textBox1.Text = MAC;
            textBox2.Text = temperature;

            MacList.Add(MAC);
            listBox1.DataSource = MacList;

        }
        
        data_tb.AppendText(in_data + "\n");


    }

    private void port_name_tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us the FORMAT of the message coming into your serial port.  It looks like they start with `&` and you're splitting on `#`.  What does the message END WITH, though? In other words, how do we know where one message stops and another starts?  Are you getting only ONE complete message per data received event?  Are there partial messages coming in?  More than one message at once, but only one data received event?

Comment: Are you sure only the first item is being added to `MacList`, or is only the first item being displayed? You're only changing `listBox1.DataSource` one time; from `null` to `MacList`. Setting it to the same reference (in other words, setting it to `MacList` after it has already been set to `MacList`) won't cause any of the events to fire. Try using a `BindingList<string>` as the type of `MacList` and set `listBox1.DataSource = MacList` in the constructor.

Comment: [link](https://ctrlv.cz/6Nw0) I divide the incoming string into two: MAC address and temperature. With each address comes the temperature that each ESP measures. Then I need to make a list of all the addresses that came to me. I'm trying to make a list of all the ESPs and what temperatures they send

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Thanks, I solved my problem by using `BindingList<string>`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

/// Try this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort myport;
    private DateTime datetime;
    private string in_data;
    List<string> MacList = new List<string>();
    public int cnt = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void stop_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            myport.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message,"Error");
        }
    }

    private void start_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        myport = new SerialPort();
        myport.BaudRate = 115200;
        myport.PortName = port_name_tb.Text;
        myport.Parity = Parity.None;
        myport.DataBits = 8;
        myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        myport.DataReceived += myport_dataReceived;
        try
        {
            myport.Open();
            data_tb.Text = "";
            
            string[] arr = in_data.Split('#');
            string MAC = arr[0];
            if !MacList.Contains(MAC))
                MacList.Add(MAC);
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message, "Error");
        }
    }

    private void myport_dataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {  
        in_data = myport.ReadLine();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
    }

    private void displaydata_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        string time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;          
        if (in_data[0] == '&')
        {            
            string[] arr = in_data.Split('#');
            string MAC = arr[0];
            string temperature = arr[3];
            textBox1.Text = MAC;
            textBox2.Text = temperature;
            // MacList.Add(MAC);
            listBox1.DataSource = MacList;

        }        
        data_tb.AppendText(in_data + "\n");
    }
}
```